# Z3Prover JavaAPI missing "getConsequence"

Tags: java, z3

To retrieve fixed assignments to the set of variables in the form of consequences. I can use `consequence` interface of `Solver` class in Z3Py. And I can find a similar API in C/C++/.Net. But I can't find the same in JavaAPI. Is this a missing in z3 JavaAPI or something else?

PS: My z3 version is `z3-4.8.7-x64-ubuntu-16.04`

Comment: Is `com.microsoft.z3.Native#solverGetConsequences(long a0, long a1, long a2, long a3, long a4)` what you are looking for?

Comment: (version: ["today's master"](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3))

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like what I am looking for. But it's from the Native package and there are no documents about the API inside. Can you tell me how to use this API?

Comment: Fixed. See here https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/3202

Comment: nice! (quick action!)